# How to combine variables with Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

Got the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
   $('a.add-item').click(function()
   {
         if ($(this).parent().find('input').attr('value', '0'))
         {
            $(this).parent().find('input').attr('value', '1')
         }
   });
});
```

What I would like to do is to create a variable and increment it and then add it to my above code replacing .attr('value', '0')) **0**

How would I go about this?

thanks,
Keith

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You mean like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
   $('a.add-item').click(function()
   {
         var $item = $(this).parent().find('input');
         var value = parseInt($item.attr('value'), 10);
         if (!value) {
             value = 0;
         }
         $item.attr('value', value + 1);
   });
});
```

Comment: You'll need to use parseInt on the value, to prevent concatenation.

Comment: You've got the right idea and thanks for replying but when I test the code, it keeps adding 1 as in 1111111 and not incrementing it. 

cheers,
Keith

Comment: Using parseInt without the second parameter is a hidden bug waiting to happen. It is best to do parseInt(val, 10) to explicitly specify the base.

Comment: @keith: that was because the input was probably empty at the begining. I added a condition to fix this

Comment: @Keith, I tested the function in a quick example and it is working as expected.

Comment: Thanks a million Nadia, perfect! really appreciate your effort

Comment: @Nadia, can you explain what this bit: $item.attr('value'), 10) - What does the 10 mean?

Comment: it's part of the parseInt( string, base) method. the 10 is the base i.e. decimal, and the string is the parent input's value

Comment: @keith: the 10 in parseInt($item.attr('value'), 10) is for specifying the int base. Without it a string that starts with "0" can be interpreted as an octal. See this for more details http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseInt.asp